# Sql query to find sum of a column in related rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like

1.GROUP_TABLE

```
Name  Under
--------------
G1    OWNED
G2    G1
G3    G2
G4    G1
G5    G2
G6    G4
G7    G2
```

2. STOCK_TABLE

   ```
   group_name    stock
   -------------------
   G1               10
   G2               20
   G3               30
   G4               10
   G5               10
   G6               10
   G7               20
   ```

In grouptable there is  groups belongs under another groups.
if i will required stock of G1 then it will retrurn 110 (sum of all under groups related to G1).
As: (G1)->(G2,G4)->(G5,G6,G7).
same with G2 -80 because (G2)->(G3,G5,G7)
and so on for G3,G4,G5,G6,G7.

I need result like

```
TillGroup           Stock
--------           --------
G1                110
G2                80
G3                30
G4                20
G5                10
G6                10
G7                20
```

Please suggest me any sql query witch will provide me same result
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which RDBMS? It's crucial in answering this question.

Comment: is is mentioned, SQL Server !

Comment: i am using Sql server 2008. and i need any way to solve this problem.

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag, as we know now that this is about SQL Server.

Comment: ok mr.  Thorsten Kettner .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use a recursive query for this:

```
with tree as 
(
  select name as master_name, name as descendant_name, under from group_table
  union all
  select 
    parent.name as master_name, 
    child.descendant_name as descendant_name, 
    parent.under
  from group_table parent
  join tree child on child.under = parent.name
)
select tree.master_name, sum(stock_table.stock)
from tree
join stock_table on stock_table.group_name = tree.descendant_name
group by tree.master_name
order by tree.master_name;
```

See SQL fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e557/26.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you very much Mr Thorsten Kettner. it works properly.

Comment: Hi @Thorsten Kettner nice answer. If possible can you help me to achieve the same thing with mysql database. I can't do it :(

Comment: @Vishal Zanzrukia: Sorry, I've never tried recursive queries in MySQL. Search for recursive query and MySQL and you will certainly find something.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Having re-read the question more carefully, my answer will not work as it does not traverse the childrens children.

```
select G.NAME, SUM(G1S.STOCK) + GS.STOCK
from GROUP_TABLE G -- consider this the parent
JOIN STOCK_TABLE GS ON GS.GROUP_NAME = G.NAME -- Get its stock number
JOIN GROUP_TABLE G1 ON G1.UNDER = G.NAME -- self-join to get all its children
JOIN STOCK_TABLE G1S ON G1S.GROUP_NAME = G1.NAME -- get the stock number for each of its children
GROUP BY G.NAME, GS.STOCK
```

Sorry, I haven't compiled this to check the syntax. There might be some small syntax errors.

Comment: thank you antman for your reply, but there is still a problem ,when i execute this query then it gives output like :  G1    40, 
G2    80,
G4    20